# How to Run Excel on a Mac? (windows edition)

Tags: excel, windows, macos, azure

I need to run the Microsoft Windows edition of Excel, but I'm using a Mac. I currently have Excel for my Mac, but it doesn't have all the functionality of Windows version. I need the advanced functionality only available in Windows edition. (Using Google Sheets isn't an option in this scenario). I have a license for Excel (both Windows and Mac editions).

I've heard Parallels (https://www.parallels.com/) is one way of doing it, but that would require me to have to purchase additional software.

I've thought about buying another computer, but I don't want to have to carry around 2 computers (one windows and one Mac).

Is there a way I could use Microsoft Azure, or some other cloud service  to rent a windows PC, install Excel  and access it from my mac?

I found this on pricing for a virtual machine, but it's not clear If it would  allow to to accomplish this.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/purchase-options/pay-as-you-go/ 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/

Any suggestions, or experience running the Windows edition of Excel from a  Mac?

Comment: Have you looked at installing Windows 10 on your Mac with Boot Camp Assistant? https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201468

Comment: Or install Windows in a VM on your Mac. I use both Parallels and Oracle Virtual Box.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bit of a stretch, but have you looked into using Bootcamp? All you have to do is partition a part of your hard drive, then you can boot into Windows and run it natively. Bootcamp is great, as long as you understand the concept and how to use it.